# Has behaviour of the summarise function changed?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an existing shiny application which, among other things, generates a table of statistics for a data frame. I have used the following code successfully for quite a while:

```
library(shiny)
#library(dashboardthemes)
library(readxl)
library(readODS)
library(tidyverse)  # data wrangling
library(viridis)    # for colour-blind friendly palettes
library(ggplot2)    # pretty plots
library(scales)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)# for statistics
library(EnvStats)
library(ggbeeswarm)

... code ...

Stats <- graphData() %>%
      group_by(Analyte) %>%
      summarise(
        .groups="keep",
        Count = sum(!is.na(Concentration)),   # Number of samples
        Minimum = min(Concentration),         # Minimum
        Average = mean(Concentration),        # Mean
        Median = median(Concentration),       # Median
        Maximum = max(Concentration),         # Maximum
        Range = Maximum - Minimum             # Range
       )
```

There are more entries, but this is sufficient to illustrate. The `graphData()` function returns a data frame with `Analyte` names and `Concentration` values.

I was making an amendment to the script is another area, and this summarise function has stopped working, giving an error that it can't find the "Maximum" value, saying "Error: object 'Maximum' not found".

Previously, I was able to refer to and use values generated inside the summarise statement after they were defined, such as in the calculation of Range here.

Has the summarise function changed behaviour or is this something else?

I'm using Rstudio.

RStudio 2023.09.0+463 "Desert Sunflower" Release (b51c81cc303d4b52b010767e5b30438beb904641, 2023-09-25) for Ubuntu Jammy
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2023.09.0+463 Chrome/114.0.5735.289 Electron/25.5.0 Safari/537.36

I can rework it with a subsequent mutate if I have to but it would be easier to keep it as it is, or close to it, if I can.

Comment: I suspect your issue is elsewhere. For instance `mtcars %>% group_by(gear)  %>% summarize(Maximum = max(mpg), Minimum = min(mpg), Range = Maximum - Minimum)` works fine for me using dplyr 1.1.2

Comment: Can you make this into a reproducible question?

Comment: I am using git, so there is that. I will do some more detailed troubleshooting when I get a chance.

Comment: that's a relief! I think rolling back to a couple of days ago (or before whenever you started doing this) and then seeing if it works should help convince you that it's not actually summarise which is broken. Barring that, including a more full example would be great

Comment: Could be a library issue - if you load `plyr` after `dplyr` then `plyr::summarize` will mask `dplyr::summarize`. I would suggest specifying `dplyr::summarize(...` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I suspect that the issue may be due to the reactive data frame, but we need to see more of the Shiny code to diagnose.